# Any php function to download an image from web and save it in my server?

Tags: php

is there a function in php which allows to download external file from another server, and put it in mine ?

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There isn't a function that will read *and* write a remote file to a new location at the same time.  That wouldn't be very useful in most cases.  It's pretty easy to accomplish with a pair of functions though:

```
file_put_contents("local-file.jpg",file_get_contents("http://x.com/img.jpg"));
```

Comment: -1 this is untrue PHP got a copy function that read a file from a url and saves it on the location you want. http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Answer (score 5):

If it's activated on your web space, you can use

[**file_get_contents()**](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents)

If you need to simulate a user-agent, do a log-in or other advanced stuff when downloading, you may want to look into the [**curl**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) family of functions.

Hard core programmers who do it themselves use [**fsockopen()**](http://de.php.net/fsockopen) and consorts to build a connection from ground up.

Comment: Thanks , i'm looking for a function which reads/ and write , thanks so much

Comment: curl can handle file uploads, too, and is probably your best bet. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692186/image-upload-using-php-curl

Comment: when i try to fwrite the image to my server, it displays error fail to access /tmp/new.jpg even my TMP directory is set to 777

Answer (score 1):

you can use fopen/fread

```
function download($src, $dst) {
        $f = fopen($src, 'rb');
        $o = fopen($dst, 'wb');
        while (!feof($f)) {
            if (fwrite($o, fread($f, 2048)) === FALSE) {
                   return 1;
            }
        }
        fclose($f);
        fclose($o);
        return 0;
}
download("http://www.somewhere/image.jpg","test.jpg");
```