# How to send a file with curl to the controller

Tags: php, cakephp, curl

I have an url with an image: http://www.example.com/image.jpg
and I have an action in the controller that uploads a file to the server by user input. I want to use this same action to upload a file by url. I started to get the data from image:

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/image.jpg";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
$rawdata=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Now how do I send the $rawdata to the controller to be handled like a normal user upload?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692186/image-upload-using-php-curl might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/image.jpg";
$filename = basename($url, rand_string(7));
$path = realpath("../webroot/uploads/")."/".$filename;


$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
$rawdata=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

if(file_exists($path)){
    unlink($path);
}

$file = fopen($path, 'x');

fwrite($file, $rawdata);
fclose($file);


$post_data['Filedata'] = '@'.$path;
$url = "http://localhost/controller/action";
$ch = curl_init();
// Set URL on which you want to post the Form and/or data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
// Data+Files to be posted
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
// Pass TRUE or 1 if you want to wait for and catch the response against the request made
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// For Debug mode; shows up any error encountered during the operation
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
// Execute the request
$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo $response;
```

In the controller:

```
function action(){

    //get properties of the file
    //$_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
    //$_FILES['Filedata']['size'];
    //$_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    //savefile();



}
```

If anyone knows how to post the file without saving it will be great.